# How can I write data to an excel table from textarea?

Tags: php, excel

I am new in coding and sufferin from some basic issues. I searched for a topic to find the answer that I need but I could not find. I've been trying to write and searching codes for writting into xls file for 3 days but could not find a suitable one. The problem is:

[image]

I created a page with textareas and submit/reset button like that and I've got an excel table in document classgrades.xls. The colums of that table are named Name, Midterm1, Midterm2, Final, Attendance and Average.

Now, I am trying to write a code which automatically adds a new row and writes user inputs from textares into the excel table. If you help I appreciate very much and if you write the code briefly I can understand better.

Comment: If you need just an `.xls` file, literally, just present/write a plain `html` table as an `.xls` file. That's it. For `.xlsx`, it's trickier (which is somehow more of a poke in the eye). Note, when opening such a `.xls` file, Excel will give a prompt asking if you want to open it.

Comment: No, I want the inputs sent by textareas to be written into a new line of a specific xls file.

Comment: So you want live editing of an Excel file? Why not use an *actual database table* for this?

Comment: Another alternative to html is csv (comma separated variable) as Excel will also happily open those. Or tab-delimited (my preference). But if you want to add to an existing XLS file...

Comment: I agree, with the above.  .csv is probably the way to go.  No need for extra libraries.  .csv files are exceedingly simple to generate and can be read by most spread sheet programs, not just Excel.  Just separate the columns with commas, or w/e delimiter you choose and the rows by the "\n" character and excel or any other spreadsheet will magically format the data as intended.

Comment: I can not use a database table or csv file because I am an intern in a company and they assigned me to do it on an excel xls table.

Comment: Dude, separate columns by commas, rows by \n, save as .csv, and open with excel.  It's that easy.  Windows by default will associate .csv files to Excel, or w/e spreadsheet program is set to default.  It is an xls file.  If your company is too rigid to allow you to do this, find a new job, they aren't worth working for.

Comment: Dude, i want to highlight the reality that i am just new in coding and i am an intern. My department in universityis about electronics but this company gave me a position about coding for internship. I know just simple things about coding (basic functions, including a class, syntax etc.). So I could not evaluate a code if it is useful for me or not. Been searching this code for long days on computer and now on the verge of going crazy because it seems to be so easy but i just can't write it. Now I just want to complete this thing and complete my internship.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class I use to modify Excel documents is PHPExcel. Was at http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/ but I just googled and it's moved to GitHib https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel.

Small warning: I have found it occasionnally buggy (turn off "NOTICE" and "WARNING" errors before diving in, for example - or at least you did when I last used it) but otherwise it's easy to use.

It has some nice classes to navigate the workbooks and add rows. No point quoting examples here as there are lots of examples in the "test" section. https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/tree/develop/Tests  Use those and piece together what you need.

Comment: Sorry, but I could not find an example fits my objective.
I am new in this job and maybe I could not see what I want because of that.
But thanks anyway

Comment: You may need to piece together the different examples. See number 7 (opening and then saving the file), mix with the worksheet iterator (to find the worksheet you need) and then example 1 ("Simple") on how to update specific calls and save. To get the values from the for, you'd use $_POST - but you're OK with that bit, aren't you? https://www.google.com/#hl=en&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=php+reading+values+from+form&oq=php+reading+values+from+form

Comment: Thanks Robbie it is helpful to understand concept and advance I am working on these examples. I appreciate your help.